# Scrolling a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel

I want a JPanel with a size and defined position. Inside the JPanel, I've certain number of elements (buttons) inserted horizontally. Because my JPanel has a defined width, if I add much buttons, I couldn't see that. In this case, I need a scrollbar for this JPanel. But this JPanel must be a CERTAIN SIZE IN A CERTAIN POSITION inside a JFrame. The scrollbar of the JPanel has positioned under it horizontally. Someone can help me? I've tried it without success!

Comment: AFAIK, the point is since your `JPanel` has one `Defined Width/Height/Size`, so once you add anything to it, which goes beyond it's size, you cannot see that thing, even with `JScrollPane` added to it, since even `JScrollPane` cannot go beyond `JPanel`'s size, so those components are hidden always :( . Since if you wont' define it's size, the components are first added to the `JPanel` and then it's `preferredSize()` is determined implicitly by `doLayout()` sort of thingies, hence your `JScrollPane` works in that situation, but not here.

Comment: Also consider [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) or a [suitable layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Without an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that clarifies the meaning of _certain size_ and _certain position_, this question cannot be answered in it's present form.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a JScrollPane and force its preferredSize to your given size (or set the scrollPane container LayoutManager to null and call setBounds() on the scrollpane). Also set the scrollbar policies. Here is a small sample of that:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("Hello-" + i));
        }
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setBounds(50, 30, 300, 50);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Emm, the problem is that I need to locate the JPanel in a specific position of the JFrame. Additionally, it must has a definite size.

Comment: @BrallanAguilar either you use a LayoutManager to position and size your components, either set the LayoutManager to null and call setBounds() to position and size your component. In this case, you must do that on the JScrollPane

Comment: Can you help me with an example, please?

Comment: @BrallanAguilar I edited my post to show how it is possible to force location and size of the JScrollPane

Comment: Hey, I've a question: why you put the layout of the contentPane null?

Comment: @BrallanAguilar As I said, either you use a LayoutManager and let him position and size the components (based on min/max/pref size and constraints), either your set the LayoutManager to null, like I did, and you force the size and position (the bounds) yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Add all the buttons to your panel. Then add this panel to scrollpane.

```
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);
panel.add(button3);
.
.
.
panel.add(buttonn);
```

Once you add buttons in panel, add panel to scrollpane.

```
JScrollPane panelPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

And then add this panel to your frame.

Comment: Sorry, but I need the part of the JPanel in a determinate size and position. Also, the orientation of the scrollbar :)

Comment: Sorry little poor in english.. `determinate` means?

Comment: Arr, is possible if post a little example with the requirements I wrote?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some possible solutions:

- [JList with JButtons and JPanel with JButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315718/714968)

or

- for scrolling to the decision `Point` or `Rectangle` there exists the method `scrollRectToVisible` e.g. `myPanel.scrollRectToVisible(myButton.getBounds());`