# Using JscrollPane in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I am using the NetBeans 8.0 IDE to design a java desktop application.
  this is how the swing components are stacked in the application.

```
   JFrame
        |
        JPanel -- this has a card layout
              |
             updateScrollPane
                            |
                            UpdateJPanel -- free flow 
                                      |
                                     Table_ScrollPane 
                                                   |
                                                   jTabble
```

the issue is that the TableScrollPane does not scroll both vertically and horizontally. The scrollBarPo;icy used are As_Needed for both vertical and horizontal.

The vertical scrollng functions as expected but the vertical does not scroll.

any suggestion is welcomed,

Comment: reading of concrete Oracle tutorials about topics will help you

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2452694/230513).

Comment: Thanks , just checked the link and the suggestion fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use a JScrollPane and force its preferredSize to your given size (or set the scrollPane container LayoutManager to null and call setBounds() on the scrollpane). Also set the scrollbar policies.

Here is the similar case: [Scrolling a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346449/scrolling-a-jpanel)